# Create cross-table, how to define in ModelBuilder?

Tags: .net, sqlite, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

Table `Instances` several user can write to. To keep them I created a table `User` and the crosstable `UserInstances`:

```
CREATE TABLE "Instances" 
(
    "SOPInstanceUID" TEXT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_Instances" PRIMARY KEY,
    "ImageComments" TEXT NULL,
    "ImportTime" TEXT NULL,
    "Tags" TEXT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE "User" 
(
    "UserID" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Account" TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("UserID" AUTOINCREMENT)
)

CREATE TABLE "UserInstances" 
(
    "UserInstancesID"   INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    "UserID"    INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES User(UserID),
    "SOPInstanceUID"    TEXT NOT NULL REFERENCES Instances(SOPInstanceUID),
    PRIMARY KEY("UserInstancesID" AUTOINCREMENT)
)
```

The `Instance` table was already implemented. The container class (`UserImports` element has been added lately):

```
public class Instance
{
    public string SOPInstanceUID { get; set; }
    public string? ImageComments { get; set; }
    public string? Tags { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ImportTime { get; set; }

    public string? Tags { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserImport> UserImports { get; set; }
}
```

The crosstable:

```
public class UserInstances
{
    public int UserInstancesID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string? SOPInstanceUID { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
    public Instance Instance { get; set; }
}
```

User container class:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string? Account { get;set; }
}
```

The `DbContext`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasKey(s => s.UserId);
modelBuilder.Entity<UserInstances>().HasKey(s => s.UserInstancesID);
modelBuilder.Entity<Instance>().HasKey(i => i.SOPInstanceUID);
```

I've added the new `UserInstance` class:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserInstances>(
            dob =>
            {
                dob.ToTable("Instance");
                dob.HasOne(s => s.Instance).WithOne().HasForeignKey<UserInstances>(o => o.SOPInstanceUID);

                dob.ToTable("User");
                dob.HasOne(s => s.User).WithOne().HasForeignKey<User>(o => o.UserId);
            });
```

When selecting a certain `Instance` I'd like to find all `User` info from the `User` table at my `UserImport` property. How can I do so?

Comment: Add more details, which DTO you need at the end?

Comment: Sure. At present the "Instances" are being used as DTO. As there are several user who can write to that DB object I now need the users who are asscociates with that Instances object. So a user can have several Instances he has written to and an Instance several Users who had modified it.

Comment: If by `crosstable` you mean a `join table`, you can model it explicitly. In EF Core  7, if not 6, you may be able to omit the join entity [if the table follows naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#basic-many-to-many). In the documentation example there's no `PostTag` entity and yet Posts map to Tags through the PostTags table automatically